# Haydn sonata Landon 1

Tags: piano, notation

[image]

Under the 4th measure on the Andante movement, there are a few extra small measures, what does that mean?

Answer (score 6):

This is an instruction how to play the trills at a) b) and c) [bars 4 and 7 of the Menuet and bar 4 of the Andante]. Check there are small letters that correspond to each trill.